# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /content\model\2016/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I ran the code

```
export_path=os.getcwd()+'\\model\\'+'2016'

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["myTag"], export_path)          
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
#    print(graph.get_operations())
    input = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    output = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')    
#     print(sess.run(output,
#                feed_dict={input: [test_data[1]]}))
    tf.train.write_graph(freeze_session(sess), export_path, "my_model.pb", as_text=False)
```

and incurred the following error

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-b154e11ca364> in <module>()
      3 
      4 with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
----> 5     tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["myTag"], export_path)          
      6     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
      7 #    print(graph.get_operations())

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py in parse_saved_model(export_dir)
     81                   (export_dir,
     82                    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PBTXT,
---> 83                    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
     84 
     85 

OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /content\model\2016/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

It was previously ran in Windows system and now IOS. I am not sure if it was because of this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid using a fixed character as directory separator (like `\` in your example), as that character differs between operating systems (see [os.sep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20sep#os.sep)).
You might want to use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) or [Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) to build your path, thereby ensuring suitable paths for the executing operating system are created, e.g.:

```
export_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'model', '2016')
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer but it seems nothing had changed:/